# There's or there're?

Tags: sentence-construction

I was watching a movie and the actor said
" There's other candy too besides chocolate" my question why he use there's candy is a plural he should use there are
and
why he said "besides" instead of "beside"

Comment: _Besides_ means _as well as_.

Comment: The actor used correctly 'candy' as a non-count noun (or 'mass' noun), and we must use the singular for that.

Comment: @KateBunting In this context, I'd say "besides" means "other than". "*There's other candy **as well as** chocolate*" isn't correct.

Comment: "candy is a plural" <-- Please explain why you believe this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Candy" in that context is an uncountable *mass noun* referring to candy in general, rather than individual pieces of candy, so "there is" is correct.